# IONIC camera plugin FILE_URI returning different file path format based on selected file type (video/picture)

Tags: android, ionic-framework, camera, android-camera, cordova-plugins

I have a problem where the uri returned is in the format:

**"content://com.android.providers.media.documents/document/image%3A18112"**

instead of:

**"/storage/emulated/0/WhatsApp/Media/WhatsApp Animated Gifs/VID-20191026-WA0003.mp4"**

This seems to only be a problem when selecting a picture from the gallery. With video files it is the correct format.
my version for the plugin is:

**"@ionic-native/camera": "^5.15.1"**

**"cordova-plugin-camera": "^4.1.0"**

Which are the latest versions for as far as I know.
I am testing on a samsung galaxy S8.

My code is below:

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { CameraOptions, Camera, MediaType } from '@ionic-native/camera/ngx';
import { CameraProviderResponse } from '../objects/cameraProviderResponse';

@Injectable()
export class CameraProvider {

    constructor(public camera: Camera) {

    }

    openCamera(selectedMediaType: MediaType, allowedMediaType: MediaType): Promise<CameraProviderResponse> {
        const options: CameraOptions = {
            sourceType: this.camera.PictureSourceType.SAVEDPHOTOALBUM,
            destinationType: this.camera.DestinationType.FILE_URI,
            mediaType: selectedMediaType
        };
        return this.camera.getPicture(options).then((mediaPath) => {
            let re = /(?:\.([^.]+))?$/;
            let fileExtension = re.exec(mediaPath)[0];
            let mediaType;
            if (fileExtension === '.jpeg' || fileExtension === '.jpg' || fileExtension === '.png' || fileExtension === '.gif' && (allowedMediaType === MediaType.ALLMEDIA || allowedMediaType === MediaType.PICTURE)) {
                mediaType = MediaType.PICTURE;
            }
            else if (fileExtension === '.mp4' && (allowedMediaType === MediaType.ALLMEDIA || allowedMediaType === MediaType.PICTURE)) {
                mediaType = MediaType.VIDEO;
            }
            else {
                return this.openCameraFailed();
            }
            return {
                success: true,
                mediaPath: mediaPath,
                mediaType: mediaType,
                fileExtension: fileExtension

            };
        }, error => {
            return this.openCameraFailed();
        }).catch(error => {
            console.log(error);
            return this.openCameraFailed();
        });
    }

    openCameraFailed(): CameraProviderResponse {
        return {
            success: false
        };
    }
}
```

If you need more information. Please ask.

Comment: "I have a problem where the uri returned is in the format" -- why is that a problem? Getting a `content` `Uri` is perfectly normal. You also have no access to filesystem paths like the one you cited on Android 10 (by default) and Android R+ (for all apps).

Comment: Ok, so how can I then get the file extension of the picture selected? And why do videos and gifs work and images not?

Comment: "so how can I then get the file extension of the picture selected?" -- there is no file extension. As with the Web, Android relies more on MIME types than file extensions. "And why do videos and gifs work and images not?" -- they are all working. If anything, the filesystem path results that you are getting are the wrong ones.

Comment: This always worked and only recently stopped working when the filepath returned changed for pictures. So for videos and gifs it still works. So for me the ones without the file extension are not working.

Comment: Anybody got a solution?

Comment: Try using cordova plugin filepath which will convert your image uri to actual file path

Comment: Ok, I did the above solution by resolving using the cordova plugin. Now it works for pictures. but the urls of the video files can't get resolved. I think my follow up question is: how can i make sure that whatever file is chosen: i always get the same uri format. Or the one with the extension, or the one without. Just a consistent format returned from getpicture().

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I currently fixed it like this:

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { CameraOptions, Camera, MediaType } from '@ionic-native/camera/ngx';
import { CameraProviderResponse } from '../objects/cameraProviderResponse';
import { FilePath } from '@ionic-native/file-path/ngx';
//bug: temp fix stack overflow post: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58581038/ionic-camera-plugin-file-uri-returning-wrong-filepath?noredirect=1#comment103477183_58581038
@Injectable()
export class CameraProvider {

  constructor(public camera: Camera, public filePath: FilePath) {

  }

  openCamera(selectedMediaType: MediaType, allowedMediaType: MediaType): Promise<CameraProviderResponse> {
    const options: CameraOptions = {
      sourceType: this.camera.PictureSourceType.SAVEDPHOTOALBUM,
      destinationType: this.camera.DestinationType.FILE_URI,
      mediaType: selectedMediaType
    };
    return this.camera.getPicture(options).then((mediaPath) => {      
      let fileExtension = this.getFileExtension(mediaPath);
      if(this.getMediaType(fileExtension) === null) {
        return this.filePath.resolveNativePath(mediaPath)
        .then(path => {
          return this.getCameraProviderResponse(allowedMediaType, path);
        })
        .catch(err => {
          console.log(err);
          return this.openCameraFailed();          
        });
      }
      else {
        return this.getCameraProviderResponse(allowedMediaType, mediaPath);
      }
    }, error => {
      return this.openCameraFailed();
    }).catch(error => {
      console.log(error);
      return this.openCameraFailed();
    });
  }

  getCameraProviderResponse(allowedMediaType: MediaType, path:string) {
    let fileExtension = this.getFileExtension(path);
    let mediaType = this.getMediaType(fileExtension);
     if(mediaType === null) {
       return this.openCameraFailed();
     }
      return {
        success: true,
        mediaPath: path,
        mediaType: mediaType,
        fileExtension: fileExtension

      };
  }

  //fix for android
  getFileExtension(path: string) {
    let re = /(?:\.([^.]+))?$/;
    return re.exec(path)[0];
  }
  //fix for android
  getMediaType(fileExtension: string) {
    if (fileExtension === '.jpeg' || fileExtension === '.jpg' || fileExtension === '.png' || fileExtension === '.gif') {
      return MediaType.PICTURE;
    }
    else if (fileExtension === '.mp4') {
      return MediaType.VIDEO;
    }
    else return null;
  }

  openCameraFailed(): CameraProviderResponse {
    return {
      success: false
    };
  }
}
```

It feels a bit hacky but it does the trick for now. Buying me some time to take a closer look at the issue. If I find a better solution I'll post it here as well! In the meantime. If anyone else finds a better solution to this problem, please post it here!